# Enumerate over nodes of an element sets in ABAQUS/Viewer

Tags: python, abaqus

Is  there any way to access nodes of an element set in ABAQUS viewer. 
I know how to extract the nodes from the connectivity by

```
session.openOdb(name='cube.odb').rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].elementSets['CUBE-1_CUBE'].elements[el_numerator].connectivity[nod_numerator]
```

The problem here is in this case we will get duplicate node numbers and we have to remove the duplicated nodes with another commands. 
I was wondering if we could directly enumerate on the nodes in the element set.

Regards

Comment: in case you haven't checked, if the element set was created from a geometry set in the abacus GUI, there will be a corresponding node set with the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways of obtaining all nodes from an element set.

The first way is what you've described. Iterate through all elements in the element set, look at each element's connectivity and filter out duplicate nodes. Here you need to be careful to also use node's instance name in case you have assembly level sets.

```
odb = session.openOdb(name='cube.odb')
elset = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].elementSets['CUBE-1_CUBE']

elset_nodes = set()

for element in elset.elements:
    elset_nodes.update(element.connectivity)

# At this point elset_nodes contains all element set nodes
```

The second approach is to create a display group out of desired element set and plot it. This will produce a `DisplayGroupInstace` object, which has method `nodes`. This method returns a dictionary containing all nodes which are part of the display group. Keys are instance names and values are node labels.

```
from abaqus import session
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo

leaf = dgo.LeafFromElementSets(elementSets='PART-1-1.CUBE-1_CUBE')

vp = session.viewports[session.currentViewportName]
vp.odbDisplay.displayGroup.replace(leaf=leaf)

dg = vp.odbDisplay.displayGroup
dg = session.DisplayGroup(name='CUBE-1_CUBE', objectToCopy=dg)
vp.odbDisplay.setValues(visibleDisplayGroups=(dg, ))

cube_dg = vp.odbDisplay.displayGroupInstances['CUBE-1_CUBE']

elset_nodes = cube_dg.nodes()
```

Comment: even more compactly: `elset_nodes=set([node for node in el.connectivity for el in elset])`

Comment: @agentp True, a better approach.

Comment: @hgazibara Thanks, I ended up using the first way.

Comment: @Amirsmol Please don't forget to mark answers as accepted (by clicking the checkmark). That's the best way to show thanks.